# boot partition updates

Tags: mount, opensuse

I'v been install and starting using OpenSuse 15 at my disk several weeks ago, the special setup of this installation that is I chose the `/boot` located in a USB pendrive, so no boot partition needed on my hard drive.

The first time I have  OpenSuse 15 updated without the USB pendrive plugged in, the system crashed until with it, but since then seems it doesn't need it to participate in updating, no crash anymore.

Would it be better updating the system with the boot partition which is in my USB pendrive?

Answer (score 0):

Typically `/boot` is needed when updating the system only when the updates include:

- an updated kernel package
- anything that causes the initramfs file to be updated (e.g. an updated kernel module)
- an updated bootloader

If the set of updates to be installed does not include any of those, then there will be no modifications to `/boot`.

Comment: How to verify if my kernel has been updated or not both in USB and local drive?

Comment: To check the kernel version: 
 
uname -r 
 
4.12.14-lp150.12.25-default 

Is it the latest? is it OK?

Comment: I don't have an OpenSuse 15 VM at hand, but assuming the layout is similar to SLES 12, you should see in `/boot` one or more files named `vmlinuz-<kernel version string>` -  they should correspond to kernel packages you have installed on your system. According to  your `uname -r`, you seem to be using the default kernel packages, so run `rpm -q kernel-default` to see which kernel versions the package management system thinks you **should** have installed right now. The version number of the newest `vmlinuz`file and the `uname -r` output should both match the latest kernel package installed.

Comment: If `rpm -q kernel-default` listing includes a kernel package version that's newer than your `uname -r`, then you are currently missing an update, and in that case you should make sure the USB is mounted and then reinstall the latest kernel-default package. (For example, just command the package management tools to remove that specific version of the kernel-default package and then to install it again.)

Comment: Before inserting the bootable USB I find my system also contains a boot folder under /, which contains some <kernel version string> are newer than the files in my USB. I'v never known boot mountpoint in USB and update without it would cause me using old version kernels. Thank you telling me the truth.

Comment: If you already reinstalled the latest kernel with the USB mounted, you can just unmount the USB and then remove any kernel files from the `/boot` folder, as they will be un-necessary duplicates now (the ones that will actually be used will be on the USB). Keep the folder, as it will be needed as a mount point for the USB.